# App launches in full screen in simulator, but not on device

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

This is an Xcode 6 Swift project. When choosing iPhone 5 or 5s in the simulator, the app launches at full screen height. However, when running the app on an actual device (an iPhone 5s), the screen is only iPhone 4 in height (i.e. black bars appear at the top and bottom of the screen).

The strange thing is that I've re-created this project from another test project - and in the original project I didn't have this problem.

I've performed a text-compare on the storyboard xml files for each, and both are mostly identical. I've also looked at the Build Settings for each, and can't see any obvious differences. Finally, the json files specified in the "Images.xcassets" directory for each are the same.

Comment: Check your splash images set, you might have missed the one required for bigger screens support while it is still packaged at the app directory for simulator.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Managed to fix the problem. In the General settings for the target, under "App Icons and Launch Images" I clicked the "Use Asset Catalog" button and followed the options.

[image: App Icons and Launch Images screenshot]

Comment: Weird bug! This happened to me as well. Just by setting the launch images to use the asset catalog fixed this problem. No need to even use launch images, just setting this option is enough. This should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: You saved me a LOT of time. (The word "lot" is capitalised to indicate that I just squealed with pure joy).

Comment: Thanks buddy, seriously a weird issue. thanks for saving my time +1 :)

Comment: I have this problem but there's no "Use Asset Catalog" Button when I navigate here. It just says "include all app icon assets" with a checkbox

Answer (score 2):

Place the Launch screen images for both iphone 5 and iphone 4 . Put the size of the default-568@2x image as 640 x 1136 .

May be you missed this size of splash screen in your project.

Comment: I did try this, but still the screen height wasn't correct. Only by clicking the "Use Asset Catalog" button as described in my answer (with or without splash screen images) did the screen height display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was fixed after adding the images with all sizes

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was because I'd saved the file in photoshop format, but with a PNG extension.  The emulator loaded the file, but the actual device couldn't.  Wasted 3 hours messing with asset catalogs before I figured it out!

[Blog post on subject](http://www.cwgtech.com/saving-a-psd-file-with-a-png-extension-%F0%9F%98%AB/)