# XCode 6 UIViewController not resizing to fill screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm creating an app without Storyboard on XCode 6.4 and when I run the app, no matter which simulator I use, I always get a `(320,480)` screen.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Ref img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGHmt.png

Already tryed:

```
vc.view.autoresizingMask = 
             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

What should I do to make it fill the whole screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, You should set launch image of your app about `default-568@2x.png` with  **640 x 1136** pixel size. 
More info --> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329903/app-launches-in-full-screen-in-simulator-but-not-on-device)

Also setting `@2x` `@3x` image assest will be good for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add launch screen. It will be solved.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html

Comment: I had to add the launch image, although your solution works too. I don't have enough reputation to vote up though..

Comment: Please just mark my answer is correct for others can refer. You can do it. Thanks